# SQL SERVER FULL-TEXT INDEX, CONTAINS return empty

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, contains, full-text-indexing

I got a issue about full index, any body can help me on this?

1) set up full text index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Companies(my table name)
(
CompanyName(colum of my table) 
Language 0X0
)
KEY INDEX IX_Companies_CompanyAlias ON QuestionsDB
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
GO
```

2) Using CONTAINS to find the matched rows

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName
FROM dbo.Companies
WHERE CONTAINS(CompanyName,'Micro')
```

3) All is going well. just just just return empty resultset. And I am sure there is company with CompanyName "Microsoft" in Table Company

Much appreciated if anybody does me a favor on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CONTAINS(CompanyName,'Micro')` is looking for the word `Micro`, if you want a prefix match to pick up "`Microsoft`" use the syntax: `CONTAINS(CompanyName,'"Micro*"')`.

Comment: Alex , you are correct, I use your method, it works for me. much appreciated!

Comment: @max - Glad you got it sorted. You should click the tick to the left of Alex's answer to mark it as answered.

Comment: @Martin, thnx for reminding since this is my first post at Stackoverflow.